# When does it stop being an answer and start becoming something else?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This "Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310769/bulletin-board-database-optimisation) and its answer are long, redacted excessively, and reads more like a dialog than an answerable question and a satisfying answer. Does this strike anyone else as inappropriate?

Comment: I no longer feel like I write too much in my posts.

Comment: Seems like shoving a forum format onto a Q&A site.

Comment: Damn. I've seen scientific papers shorter than that.

Comment: I certainly can't be bothered to read it. But it might very well answer the php board optimization topic with reusable advises. At first glance it looks "too localized", but what actually makes it stand out on SO is that most other Q&As are in-a-hurry and too broad or answered too undetailed.

Comment: Ups, I was affraid that my answers are sometimes too long and nobody reads them. This looks insane :)

Comment: ... Jesus Christ

Comment: I'm in shock.  Voting to close as Too localized, perhaps?

Comment: If that is not the very definition of "too broad", then "too broad" has no meaning. For Buddha's sake, they are already at **point 41**!

Comment: Crap, my mouse wheel is broken now.

Comment: What kills me is that surely this is a solved issue. I understand why people compete in an occupied marketplace; maybe you'll do it better or maybe you'll do it worse but still make money. But is there a lot of unexplored bulletin board territory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does this strike anyone else as inappropriate?

Yes it does, and I left them a comment that I'll follow up on later.

This looks like an isolated incident though, so I'm not too worried about this becoming a trend.  There are better tools available for collaborating on projects, and those two don't have enough time before the heat death of the universe to clutter up the site with many more posts of that length.